# Networkx extracting list of connected components subgraphs of certain dimension: incorrect counts

Tags: python, list, networkx, subgraph

I have extracted a list of all connected components of a graph G as list of subgraphs this way:

```
sg = list(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G))
```

Then I made some counts:

```
n_conn_comp = nx.number_connected_components(G) # >>> 172305
n_isolated_nodes = len(nx.isolates(G)) # >>> 152403
n_subgraf_dimensionMoreThan1 = n_conn-comp - n_isolated_nodes # >>> 19902
len(sg) # >>> 172305
```

Until here everything ok.
Then my task is to extract a list of connected components with dimension bigger than 1 (at least 2) as a list of subgraph.
'Cause there is not such a library command in NetworkX (or Am I wrong?!), I tried doing it this way:

```
for elem in sg:
    if len(elem) == 1:
        sg.remove(elem)
```

This code gives no error. I expected that now len(sg) was = n_subgraf_dimensionMoreThan1, and so = 19902. So I checked this:

```
len(sg)
```

But the result is:

```
>>> 91620
```

Much more than expected (19902)
I really can't find out what went wrong. I also tried the same code to remove strings of len 1 into a list of strings of different len, and it works fine and correctly.

May with list of subgraphs things go in different way..

Any suggestion?! Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove items from a list while iterating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: You are right, in fact i finally found the solution reading the post you linked. May I have to remove my question..?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because you are removing items from the same list you are iterating through. For example:

```
>>> sg = range(20)
>>> for i in sg:
        sg.remove(i)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

The solution is to make one copy of sg to iterate through and another copy to call your .remove() method on.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this way: (list comprehension )

```
sg_MoreThan1 = [el for el in sg_notdeg if len(el)!=1]
```

In fact:

```
len(sg_MoreThan1)
>>> 19902
```

Thanks anyway.